# How to deal with linked "debug me" websites with a small & concrete problem?

Tags: discussion

*This mostly refers to websites, specifically HTML/CSS/JS:*

Recently I saw a question in HTML/CSS where a user had a problem on a live website. They only linked the page and exactly described the one problem (horizontal scrolling on mobile/responsive) they had. I found the cause in 10 seconds, as I dealt with this exact thing before, but I needed "Inspect element".

I personally had this problem many times that after a while you reach the point where you're so much in the code, that the most obvious things slip your eye. In those cases it's good to have a second pair of eyes look over it and point out the problem. I use my co-worker for this, but by far not everyone can do that.

Now, I know just linking a site is against SO rules, but in some cases it may just be a small (non-obvious) thing that causes the problem. Posting code wouldn't help that much, since the problem could lie anywhere in the page, so we can't really expect the user to recreate half the page in SO/JSfiddle.

So how do we deal with these questions? Most get downvoted to oblivion or closed and I get it, but is there no place for these types of questions, where someone has a concrete problem, describes it as well as possible and just wants someone to give a look? Maybe a tag or a subpage/category of SO? We'd have the knowledge and a link to view the source/code/inspect the element to help them, so we COULD help them, but don't, because of the asker-rules. So do we just flag and ignore them?

Thanks!

P.s. I know this could be a pandora's box of "debug this for me" questions, so I'm referring only to users with one concretely, well and precisely described problem.

Comment: *but is there no place for these types of questions* sure, reddit, Quora spring to mind.

Comment: Downvote, close vote, and delete vote such questions as they are wholly off-topic for Stack Overflow. That you feel they are answerable despite being wholly off-topic is completely irrelevant. There are plenty of places all over the web where such questions are not off-topic, this just isn't one of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So how do we deal with these questions?

I don't believe there needs to be a change in how these issues are handled.

> Most get downvoted to oblivion or closed and I get it, but is there no place for these types of questions, where someone has a concrete problem, describes it as well as possible and just wants someone to give a look?

By all means, provide your screenshots and live links but remember, bugs are (generally) created in code, so provide that over other things to make everyone's life easier. As for wanting someone to have a look, wouldn't it be easier if the OP just provided the minimal code so people can quickly spot issues in that rather than having to go through the site and find the problematic areas?

> Posting code wouldn't help that much, since the problem could lie anywhere in the page, so we can't really expect the user to recreate half the page in SO/JSfiddle.

And what if does exist anywhere in their site/code?

Should the OP not be expected to debug *their* own code and narrow down *their* issue to make it easier for those people providing *free* help?

> Maybe a tag or a subpage/category of SO?

The vast majority of these sort of questions aren't at the standards you describe and as such I sincerely believe this would just be abused and would create *even more* work in the queues and that is something we just don't need.

> We'd have the knowledge and a link to view the source/code/inspect the element to help them, so we COULD help them, but don't, because of the asker-rules.

Absolutely, we *COULD* help them but *SHOULD* we?

They are showing a blatant disregard of the rules.

> So do we just flag and ignore them?

You could:

- Flag, down-vote/close-vote and just leave it
- You could comment and guide the OP to include the/some code
- You could try and edit the question into shape through your inspecting to provide a minimal example (though be aware of licensing violations of the code you are copying across)

Comment: Editing the code into the question for the OP may be a license violation if the license that applies to the code is not compatible with cc-by-sa.

Comment: @TinyGiant excellent point. Updated to include that warning.

Answer (score 6):

> so I'm referring only to users with one concretely, well and precisely described problem

No, you're not.  You're referring to questions that link to a site and fail to adequately describe or provide an adequate example of the problem in the question, which are the types of questions that we actually want.

If people want to be able to ask the question they need to *ensure the question actually contains enough information to answer it*, so that the question can actually serve the site's function and continue to be useful to the programming community at large by providing as a reference to others with the same problem who can come upon the question and be helped by an existing solution, without needing to re-ask the question because the previous person to ask it just linked to their site instead of describing the problem and including the relevant information *in the actual question*.

If you think that a question with this problem could become an interesting question that would be a useful addition to the site's repository of knowledge then *edit the question* so that the information needed to answer it is *in the actual question* (while containing as little irrelevant information/code as possible, so that the question is understandable).

The mission of the site is not to provide a solution to one person while leaving nothing useful behind for anyone else with the same problem.  There are sites that *are* designed that way, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: OP should also note that using this style of questions the uquestion content will be destroyed when the error is fixed on the production-website. So should we just ask the user to keep the error so his SO-question remains intact?

Comment: If e.g something breaks your layout, it could be a nested div or something somewhere in the footer. Of course a user can be expected to debug/find it out themselves, but that can be applied to ANY question here. Sometimes you just don't see it. I think as you and piet.t mention, the problem is my understanding of the SO focus. I don't really answer questions just to enlargen SO's knowledge base. I answer to help the asker (crazy, right). So my second part of the question would be: is there another place for these questions where I could redirect them? Like sometimes I redirect them to Reddit

Comment: @elveti '*I don't really answer questions just to enlargen SO's knowledge base. I answer to help the asker (crazy, right).*' So your reason for using the site doesn't match SO's purpose so we should change the site's purpose?

Comment: @Script47 *sigh* sure, that's exactly what I meant......

Comment: @elveti Would you care to explain what else you could've meant with your post and the above comment in mind?

Comment: @Script47 1) I misunderstood SO's purpose. 2) I asked if there are other portals (SO or outside of SO) to redirect such users (who are actual people with a specific, solvable problem). But it doesn't matter, as you mentioned in your comment (thanks for the comment btw), in the future I'll try to edit the questions and push the asker to include more details in the question. I agree with all points mentioned for >95% of these types of questions, but for the (admittedly small) rest I kinda feel bad for not being able to help.

Comment: Users who cannot create a minimal, complete, reproducible example demonstrating the problem are in need of a *consultant*, not a Q&A site. The point is not really who it is our mission to help. Rather, it is that there is a fundamental need to make each question self-contained. This is impossible if the question relies on a link to an external resource (whether a personal website needing debugging or any other content).

Comment: @CodyGray I suspect that were a site to be designed around answering a question for the author, and then having that question just go away and not be a resource for others, that they probably wouldn't be very strongly opposed to going to a linked site as a demo.  Part of *why* SO needs questions to be self contained is so that they can stand the test of time, because they're there to be a reference to people for a long time to come, rather than something to discard the second the OP gets an answer.